# SMTP.starttls() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keyfile'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to send email with this code:

```
send_mail(
            subject='Restore password',
            message='Restore password for ' + email,
            from_email=os.environ.get('GMAIL_EMAIL', ''),
            html_message=html_message,
            recipient_list=[email]
        )
```

And having this error

```
SMTP.starttls() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keyfile'
```

My python version is 3.12.0

My Django version is 4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL

```
Changed in version 3.12: The deprecated keyfile and certfile parameters have been removed.
```

After I updated Django version to 4.2.7 everything worked good.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Django==4.2.7
and if you're using drf then djangorestframework==3.14.0
and Also Google has remove less security apps
goo to your Google account Click on manage account search App password create
app it will generate a password use it in your env but make sure two step verification will be configured on your Email